# Turning a function call which takes a callback into a coroutine

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-coroutine

I am exploring and trying to learn C++ Coroutines (added in C++20). An SDK I am using has asynchronous API calls which all take a callback, the callbacks are invoked on some background thread managed by the SDK.

```cpp
namespace third_party {

bool api_call(const std::string& some_parameter, const std::function<void(std::error_code)>& callback);

} // namespace third_party
```

I would like wrap this API call into something which can be awaited instead:

```cpp
namespace my_third_party_sdk_wrapper {

cppcoro::task<std::error_code> api_call(const std::string& some_parameter);
cppcoro::task<std::error_code> api_call(const std::string& some_parameter, cppcoro::cancellation_token token);

} // namespace my_third_party_sdk_wrapper
```

I am considering using the [cppcoro](https://github.com/lewissbaker/cppcoro) lib but that isn't a requirement unless the implementation of the wrapper gets much simpler by doing so.

The problem is I cannot figure out how implement the wrapper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a really good article by Raymond Chen, you can find it [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20191218-00/?p=103221).

In your case, you can do something like this.

```cpp
namespace my_third_party_async_sdk_wrapper 
{

    auto api_call_async(const std::string& some_parameter)
    {
          struct awaiter : public std::experimental::suspend_always
          {
               awaiter(const std::string &parameter)
               :parameter_(parmeter) {}

               bool await_ready() { return true; }

               void await_suspend(std::experimental::coroutine_handle<> handle)
               { 
                   // use your third party lib call directly here.
                   api_call(parameter_, [](std::error_code ec) 
                   { 
                       // call the handle to resume the coroutine
                       handle(); 
                   }
               }
          };
          return awaiter(some_parameter);
    }

}
```

This should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks! Just a quick Q, the original callback takes a parameter, where would I put that? Does it go into the `coroutine_handle<>` type?

Comment: I made some edits, I made two mistakes. 1) The await_ready needs to return false, to tell the machine to call await_suspend immediately. 

You store the parameters in the awaiter, and then when it is suspended, it calls the api_call with the member parameters. Then when your api_call calls it's callback, you call the handle() to resume. 

This doesn't really handle out-params or return values. Which you can do by passing a reference into your awaiter, and assigning it. _But_, you need to be careful the reference lives long enough.

Comment: The 3pp `api_call` expects a `void(std::error_code)` function but you provide a `void()` function. I don't know anything about coroutines, but that doesn't look right. Also, the `experimental` types you use are now included in gcc for example so perhaps you could update it so it compiles? I came here via a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73581608/wrap-callback-api-into-coroutine) and that poster referred to your answer but couldn't figure out how to work with it.

Comment: I see. I will edit to correct. The point of the awaiter is to call the async call on suspend, and resume when the call completes.

Answer (score 1):

a simple (running) example on cppreference.com, "switch_to_new_thread": https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines

open are two problems:

- passing a parameter to the callback
- chaining the callbacks down the callstack

this code shows a solution https://wandbox.org/permlink/OGjmtFWsgjnn3GxX

look for latest version here: https://github.com/andreaspfaffenbichler/Continuation/blob/master/Continuation.cpp