# Turning callback into coroutine while keeping symmetric transfer

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-coroutine

Based on the answer of [Turning a function call which takes a callback into a coroutine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64270626/turning-a-function-call-which-takes-a-callback-into-a-coroutine) I'm able to come up with a my version of a generic `CallbackAwaiter` class that I can inherent and wait for callbacks. However I can't figure out how to make it support symmetric transfer. Causing stack overflow in certain cases (mostly in complicated business logic). My code looks like this

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct CallbackAwaiter
{
    bool await_ready() noexcept
    {
        return false;
    }

    const T &await_resume() const noexcept(false)
    {
        assert(result_.has_value() == true || exception_ != nullptr);

        if (exception_)
            std::rethrow_exception(exception_);
        return result_.value();
    }

  private:
    optional<T> result_;
    std::exception_ptr exception_{nullptr};

  protected:
    void setException(const std::exception_ptr &e)
    {
        exception_ = e;
    }
    void setValue(const T &v)
    {
        result_.emplace(v);
    }
    void setValue(T &&v)
    {
        result_.emplace(std::move(v));
    }
};

// For example. I can inherent the class and fill in `await_suspend` to convert callbacks into coroutines. 
struct SQLAwaiter : CallbackAwaiter<std::map<std::string, std::string>>
{
...
    void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<> handle)
    {
        dbClient->runSQL(..., [handle](){
            ...
            setValue(...);
            handle.resume();
        });
    }
};
```

This works. But by calling `handle.resume()` manually I don't support symmetric transfer. Which stack overflows after deep corouting resume. So far I tried adding `promise_type` and using `std::noop_coroutine` to get symmetric transfer working. For example

```
    std::noop_coroutine_handle await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<> handle)
    {
        dbClient->runSQL(..., [handle](){
            ...
            setValue(...);
            handle.resume();
        });
        return std::noop_coroutine{};
    }

// and

struct CallbackAwaiter
{
    CallbackAwaiter() : coro_(std::noop_coroutine{}) {}
    std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> coro_;
}
```

But obviously these wouldn't work. Returning `noop_coroutine` doesn't magically make `handle.resume()` not take up stack space. Nor does adding `promise_type` would work as there's no compiler generated coroutine.

I'm out of idea. How can I support symmetric transfer for such case?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, your existing code

```
    void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<> handle)
    {
        dbClient->runSQL(..., [handle](){
            ...
            setValue(...);
            handle.resume();
        });
    }
```

should already be fine.

Depending on your implementation of `dbClient->runSQL`, the callback which calls `handle.resume` will be executed on a fresh stack, with only the stack frames from the IO multiplexer, and a couple of other dbClient-internal functions on it.

Symmetric transfer is only a concern if your `runSQL` function calls its callback synchronously. As long as `runSQL` always calls its callback asynchronously (i.e. on a "fresh" stack), then you are already fine

Comment: Ohh I see. In case this `runSQL`  calls the callback synchronously. Is there a way to have symmetric transfer? (For example, when the SQL backend is SQLIte)

Comment: Afaik, for SQLite, the callback is guaranteed to be called synchronously. 
There are 3 ways how a callback can be called: (1) guaranteed synchronous - you don't need coroutines at all, (2) guaranteed async - your usage of coroutines is fine, (3) sync/async determined at runtime: in this case you will need to either modify the `runSQL` directly to support symmetric transfer or dispatch your callback yourself through the scheduler and thereby force it to be always async.