# Wrap Callback API into Coroutine-based Iterable

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-coroutine

I want to warp a typical C callback API that generates multiple `int` values  into an iterable in the fashion of `std::generator<int>` (see [p2502r1](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2502r1.pdf)).

API looks like:

```cpp
typedef void (*Callback)(int);
void api(Callback callback) {
   callback(1);
   callback(2);
   callback(3);
}
```

The API wrapper should behave like:

```cpp
for(int i : APIWrapper(&api)){
   std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

expected result:

```
1
2
3
```

I've been looking into this but couldn't figure out how to extend it accordingly:

- [Turning a function call which takes a callback into a coroutine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64270626/turning-a-function-call-which-takes-a-callback-into-a-coroutine)

I am looking for leads how to accomplish what is described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want isn't really possible with `co_await`-style coroutines. To do this, you would need to be able to suspend within the callback such that it also suspends the `api` function as well. `co_await`-style coroutines can't do that.

Comment: It was kind of what I feared to hear as an answer. I did a bit of research on suspending from within and resuming from outside the execution of a function call within a single thread. I couldn't find much. Seems like I'll have to stick to threads and synchronization primitives then. That works but comes with a considerable overhead.

Comment: @A.Bigerl: Wait: You didn't mention that the use case was already threaded. Your code above is about *synchronous* generators. Async generators are a different thing, since the generator could be on a separate thread. Is that what you're trying to do? If so, what exactly is the threaded relationship between `api`, the callback, and the code which wants to consume the values generated by `api`?

Comment: And I was looking for a synchronous generator. I would like to get rid of threading here without loosing the iterator interface. The current implementation is asynchronous. In detail: The API call is run in a detached thread and writes results to a single-producer-single-consumer queue. The queue is consumed through an iterator on the main thread. Some additional work is done to know when the API call terminates and to make sure the queue never grows too large.

Comment: @A.Bigerl: Yeah, the coroutine version would basically be that. But I hope you didn't go through the trouble of creating a thread just to make an iterator-based API. That is, I hope that the `api` process is something worth putting in another thread. If you don't actually need asynchronous processing, you could make it synchronous just by making the `api` callback fill in a `vector` that you consume. It'd be way cheaper than another thread.

Comment: Actually, the `api` is parsing RDF (tripe data) and there can be billions of triples in an RDF file. So a. thread creation overhead is neglectable and b. first filling a `vector` and then using its iterator is memory-wise not an option. As parsing is still very cheep I was wondering if I could work on a single thread and maybe gain some speed by directly using parsing results while they are in the inner CPU cache lines and not yet flushed to main memory (what necessarily happens while writing/reading them to/from the queue).

Comment: @A.Bigerl: "*As parsing is still very cheep*" *Nothing* is cheap when the word "billions" is involved. Doing that on another thread is entirely reasonable and natural. Really, I'd just stick with what you have, as a coroutine-based interface wouldn't meaningfully improve things relative to your more explicit callback+queue version. It would just be doing the same thing, only using `co_yield` to submit the value to the queue.